# How to play a song on repeat in Racket/gui?

Tags: audio, scheme, slideshow, racket, wav

I'm making a slideshow using racket and want a short song to play on loop behind the slide show. I'm currently using `(play-sound)` but Racket crashes with a segfault towards the end of the song, always at a different slide. If I run the show without the sound code it does not segfault.

I think the song ending is causing racket/gui to crash and looping might prevent this. Playing the song in the main function of the show as such

```
(define (run)
 (play-sound "path" #t)
 (slide (...)
 (run))
```

Causes the song to continuously cut out, only playing the first two seconds or so before repeating. I now have the play-sound line outside of the main function, but it does crash towards the end, sometimes at the very end. I've tried increasing DrRacket's memory but it didn't help. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Segfault? Upgrade if you haven't already. If you run the latest release, please submit a bug report.

Comment: what operating system? (and definitely do as @soegaard says)

Comment: Unless `(slide...)` ends exactly when the sound is finished it will recurse and start playing again and again getting the same clip at different starting points at the same time. Perhaps you should have made a busy loop with `async? => #f` in a procedure and start it as a separate thread?

Comment: I did upgrade Dr.racket, and I'm on a windows 8.1 x64. The segfault did stop, thank you so much. Now I'm just working on looping the audio. @Sylwester, how would I go about that? The racket documentation on threads is abysmally unhelpful. My song is about 2:20 and I have ten slides which time out after around 15 seconds each. The cutting out I mentioned about happens immediately, when i start on the first slide the son will play the first second or two before restarting continuously, no matter which slide im on. Then the song only plays fully when i stop the show.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the RSound package (cf. http://pkgs.racket-lang.org). This package will have both advantages and disadvantages over your current approach. The most obvious disadvantage will be that it will require that you convert your song to a WAV. Here's some code:

```
#lang racket

(require rsound)

(define ishmael (rs-read "/Users/clements/Desktop/call-me-ishmael.wav"))

(define LEAD-TIME (* 1/10 44100))

(define (play-forever sound)
  (define p (make-pstream))
  (define len (rs-frames sound))
  (let loop ([t 0])
    (pstream-queue p sound (+ t LEAD-TIME))
    (define next-t (+ t len))
    (sleep (* 1/44100 (- next-t (pstream-current-frame p))))
    (loop next-t)))

(play-forever ishmael)
```